# Azure VM Linux Ubuntu backup agent - Deployment failed

Tags: linux, bash, azure, ubuntu

We have two Ubuntu (14.04) Linux server VMs on Azure hosting. Currently trying to setup the backup service within Azure for these machines. I have followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-update-agent?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Flinux%2Ftoc.json) and have the agent up and running. When running "waagent -version" in bash output shows:

```
WALinuxAgent-2.2.5 running on ubuntu 14.04
Python: 2.7.6
Goal state agent: 2.2.5
```

When then attempting to enable the backup service in Azure I get the error, deployment failed, here is a snippet of the error:

```
{
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "UserErrorGuestAgentStatusUnavailable",
        "message": "Unable to perform the operation as the VM Agent is not responsive."
```

Unsure why the Agent is "not responsive" as it is installed and running.

What am I missing?

We have rebooted and restarted the server/services. Tried different backup job creations. Servers do have a load balancing set between them, but have tried disabling this to no effect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft support advised me to run these commands using the Azure powershell cmdlets:

```
Add-Azureaccount
$vm = Get-AzureVM –ServiceName <cloud service name> –Name <VM name>
$vm.VM.ProvisionGuestAgent = $true
Update-AzureVM –Name <VM name> –VM $vm.VM –ServiceName <cloud service name>
```

This did the trick! Have now been able to successfully backup the VM. This was with the walinuxagent installed from apt-get, nothing else was required in order for the service to run.

Comment: thank you for your share, please mark it as an answer, it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

I had test in my lab, I had update Waagent to version 2.2.5, then enable azure backup service, it works for me.

For test, please try to use azure portal to reset password, if the waagent does not work, reset password will **not** complete, so we should re-install waagent.

Comment: I removed the package and reinstalled then updated the agent to v2.2.5, and still no joy.

When I try to reset password via the portal, I do not have the option to. Message appears saying the VM agent is required, please install...

Comment: @dmoly According to the message, the waagent can't communicate with the azure portal, how do you re-install waagent? download the package and install it?

Comment: Yes, I ran apt-get remove, then re-installed which gave a slightly older version, then downloaded with wget the zip file from github for the latest version. Ran the python setup which updates to the 2.2.5 release. Pretty much as per the guide from the original post. Where may I be going wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @dmoly please try to use apt-get to install waagent, in my test, I have not remove old version.

Comment: No still no joy. I tried removing once again as well and ran apt-get install waagent to double check. Is there a way to test the Azure connection from the server, rather then the portal? I am only testing by checking to see if I can reset the password and attempting to redeploy the backup service from Azure.

Comment: @dmoly Have you changed your VM network settings? for example, a static private IP.  can you via the VM access the internet?

Comment: No haven't changed any settings, the VM is assigned IP via DHCP (as per Azure). It has internet access as its a web server which is accessible and working fine, and I directly SSH into the machine. We have a third linux VM which has backed up fine, and I have cross examined the settings, still unable to see why its failing. Again, appreciate your time and help on this.

Comment: @dmoly please check the logs from VM, /var/log/waagent.log    for test, we can use portal to install extension, because install extension will through waagent, so we can find the logs in it, and we can find extension logs in /var/log/azure.

Comment: in the waaagent log it pretty much shows the same 5 lines repeating once an hour:
2017/03/09 10:07:02.759753 INFO Ensuring Agent WALinuxAgent-2.2.5 is downloaded
2017/03/09 10:07:02.772857 INFO Agent WALinuxAgent-2.2.5 was previously downloaded - skipping download
2017/03/09 10:07:02.777367 INFO Agent WALinuxAgent-2.2.5 loaded manifest from /var/lib/waagent/WALinuxAgent-2.2.5/HandlerManifest.json
2017/03/09 10:08:21.793650 INFO Event: name=WALinuxAgent-2.2.5, op=HeartBeat, message=
Azure log folder is empty...?

Comment: Can you install extension via new portal?

Comment: I can only see the option to install 3rd party extensions via selecting the VM and choosing the "Extensions" option. It displays a message "Before adding an extension, install the VM Agent..." No option to deploy the waagent from Azure. Can only envoke the deployment by trying to enable a backup, I also tried a 3rd party extension to deploy the agent and that failed as well.

Comment: @dmoly We can remove walinuxagent `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove walinuxagent` and re-instal it with `apt-get install walinuxagent` Please try it, it will delete configuration and data files of walinuxagent. so we can install it new

Comment: Okay so it has installed v2.2.2 from `apt-get` Still nothing. But upon checking the waagent.log there is a message of `INFO Wait for cloud-init to copy ovf-env.xml` constantly, appears to be failing this copy of xml file.

Comment: please check if the ovf-env.xml exist or not? `/var/lib/waagent/ovf-env.xml`

Comment: Thanks Jason for all your help, we have now enlisted Microsoft support. Hopefully with their access they may find the solution. I will post the results when we get them. Thanks again.

Comment: See my answer above! All working now! Many thanks again.